# Java <-> Angular Dto

Tags: java, angular, typescript, web, web-applications

I'm going to build quiet a big application using `Java` and `Spring` as backend and `Angular4+` as frontend. Between these two layers I'm going to send some DTOs, so I'm going to have two implementation of these dto's one at `Java` side as normal `POJO` serialized into `JSON`. And at Angular implementation of these same object in `Typescipt`.

Is there any tehnology or tool or plugin, or generator to keep consistency of these two objects ? 
Or maybe some technology which from metamodel generate both java and typescipt dtos. Do you have any ideas to keep these two objects up to date, and keep consistency?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if I check the [thrift documentation on Javascript](https://thrift.apache.org/lib/js), at the bottom of the page, I see: "TypeScript definition files can also be generated by running: `thrift --gen js:ts file.thrift`" so it looks like thrift does support typescript.

Comment: Just an Advice - instead of looking for some tool and overloading your application.You can create your own factory pattern to return DTO,  which will ensure your DTO is common to that of server's DTO.

Comment: Praveen Shendge thanks  finally i'm generating dto from swagger xml file ;)

Comment: @Adrian, How are you generating angular-dto from swagger? What mechanism/lib are you using for soap-angular integration?  I have Some 4 soap interface classes, that return on nested DTO trees (java pojo), I prefer to avoid creating DTO equivalents in typescript by hand. These DTOs need to map to different parts of angular screen. Your input from experience would help.